# how to choose max_load_factor based on number of elements?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I work with `unordered_set`. 
[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_set/) it's written that it has a `reserve` function which
set buckets based on number of elements `N` to contain.
However, `mpic++` compiler on Ubuntu complains that there is no function reserve:
`class std::tr1::unordered_set<pair_int>’ has no member named ‘reserve’`

I need to optimize my set to hold `N` elements,
it seems the `max_load_factor` is available, how do I come with one based on `N`?
Or can I optimize it somehow else?

Thanks in advance

p/s/ saw some discussion for java, but not for c++ stl lib

Comment: If your compiler supports it, use the C++11 `std::unordered_set` instead of the old `tr1` version. That should have a `reserve` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load factor is independent of the number of items you insert. It's basically the percentage of available space that's actually in use. If, for example, you currently have space for 100 elements allocated, the maximum load factor could say to start resizing the table when you had inserted, say, 80 items (this would correspond to a maximum load factor of 80%).

Setting the maximum load factor is, therefore, largely independent of the number of elements you're going to store. Rather, it's (mostly) an indication of how much extra space you're willing to use to improve search speed. All else being equal, a table that's closer to full will have more collisions, which will slow searching.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optimize an unordered set to hold N elements, you want to use the rehash function.  This accepts an argument that sets the minimum buckets for the set.  This will prevent a rehash from occuring when you are inserting elements into your set.

For instance, if your desired load factor is `75%` then your bucket size should be `N / .75`

```
//  This creates an unordered set optimized for `80` elements with a load factor of `75%`
std::unordered_set<std::string> myset;
myset.rehash(120);
```

Comment: Did you mean 90 instead of 80? 90 / .75 would be 120. Also note that you can let it do the math for you and just call `myset.reserve(90);` instead (after calling `myset.max_load_factor(0.75);`).